# Dynamically created fields are not submitted

Tags: javascript, forms, form-submit

I have a code which reads from indexeddb and creates tables according to the fetched records. The adding is done by innerHTML into text fields inside a table. The problems is that when submitting the form (after updating a field for example), these fields are not submitted, only those which are physically included in the html. How to solve this? Thanks!

```
rowhlp.innerHTML = '<td><input type="text" class="bedingt" name="fieldA' + currLn + '" id="fieldA' + currLn + '" value="' + d_DArtNr + '></TD>'
```

Comment: `<input` should end with `/>` not `>`

Comment: Please share the complete HTML code

Comment: thanks moguzalp, old habits, but still...

Comment: Gowtham, the code is veeeeery long, I can just tell you that I have a for statement which calls a function for each record. The function contains the above code, which is then being inserted inside <tbody id="rowhlp">. Under the table there are some other fields, physically embeded in the HTML. I can see all these fields, static as well as dynamic, so the problem is not there. It's when submitting the form (used GET to see the submitted url), the url includes only the static fields, no those inserted in innerHTML.